# Symmetry in polynomials

Tags: polynomials, graphing-functions

Firstly, everywhere below I am only considering polynomials of degree $n$ whose derivatives have $(n-1)$ real, distinct roots.

Consider a quadratic polynomial $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$

It is known that the quadratic polynomial has an axis of symmetry at the root of its derivative, i.e. $x=-\frac{b}{2a}$

Similarly, a cubic polynomial $g(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ is centrally symmetric about the root of its second derivative $x=-\frac{b}{3a}$, by which I mean :
$$\frac{f(-\frac{b}{3a}+x)+f(-\frac{b}{3a}-x)}{2} = f\left(-\frac{b}{3a}\right)$$

Can we extend this result to all polynomials? Can we say :

> All polynomials of even degree $n$ have an axis of symmetry at the root of their $(n-1)th$ dervative, and all polynomials of odd degree $n$ have a centre of symmetry at the root of their $(n-1)th$ dervative

Comment: To make this easier, note that the root of the $(n-1)^{\text{th}}$ derivative of a polynomial with degree $n$, leading coefficient $a$, and second to leading coefficient $b$ has root $x=-\frac{b}{na}$.

Comment: If you're familiar with the Vieta relations, you'll know that the sum of the roots is equal to the negative of the coefficient of the next highest power. So your two examples correspond to looking at the *mean* of the roots.

Comment: @J. M. isn't a mathematician Isn't the sum of roots the negative of the coefficient of the next highest power _divided_ by the leading coefficient?

Comment: Yes. Notice the $a$ in the denominators of those expressions you're dealing with? And that the other factor is essentially the number of roots the polynomial has? Doesn't it look like a mean?

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician Okay, so $-\frac{b}{na}$ is basically the mean of all the roots of the polynomial.. so symmetry will only exist when the roots are symmetrically placed on both sides of the mean, right? I basically mean something like $(x+3)(x+2)(x-2)(x-3)$ will possess symmetry while $(x+1)(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$ won't